# javascript confirm dialog box before X pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need some javascript to ask the user if they want to leave the page. The code I have works whenever the page closes (not only when then user presses X). Any ideas?

This is what I have:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    if (confirm) {
        return "Are you sure?";
    }
 });
```

Comment: Please don't do this. This is the single most annoying thing you can screw up a website with. Yes, if I close the tab/window/browser, I do mean to leave the web page. No need for confirming that.

Comment: It's not possible to differentiate a browser close or a navigation. If you must, make a single-page app and/or load all data via AJAX or similar.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if it is possible to stop the browser from closing. Wouldnt' make any sense to me.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It seems that the makers of Stack Overflow would disagree with you.

Comment: X - i.e. the close button in the corner of every webpage...

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - it is a major UX consideration, it *can* be annoying. That said, it can sometimes 'save the day' when you're in the middle of a piece of writing in the browser and accidentally close it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `true/false`, not a string. Confirm has optional parameter, which you are looking for.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```